# Assigning A Specific Memory Address from another program, and changing it's value

Tags: c++, memory, variable-assignment, memory-address

Recently I've time off of school for a few days and wanted to do a small program(s) experiment  in C++ dealing with memory address.

I wanted to see is that if a currently running program (Let call it Program A) that created a pointer to an int object in the heap, can be seen by another program and be modified (Program B).

So for Program A, this is my basic code:

```
// Program A
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Pointer to an int object in the heap
    int *pint = new int(15);

    // Display the address of the memory in heap
    cout << pint << endl;

    // Display the value stored in that address
    cout << *pint << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output for Program A:

```
0x641030
15
```

For Program B, I looked at how to assigned a specific memory address through this link:
http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14104

The code for Program B is:

```
// Program B
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // assign address 0x641030 to p
    int *p = reinterpret_cast< int* > (0x641030);

    cout << p << endl;
    cout << *p << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output for Program B:

```
0x641030
... "Crash"
```

I don't quite understand it. I was expecting a display of 15 from `*p`, but it did something i didn't expect.

I also tried to assign `*p` to a number like `*p = 2000` but it crashed when I attempted that as well.

Also when I display the address of the pointers and Program A (`cout << &pint;`) and for Program B (`cout << &p;`), they both showed the same memory address.

Does anyone know what is going on exactly? I'm interested yet confused of what is happening. Also, is it possible for me to do what I am attempt in C++/C ?

** EDIT **
Sorry to not mention my platform, but I am currently using Window 7 Professional

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is that different processes use completely different address spaces. Without doing a lot more work, process B can't read or write the memory from process A.

It is possible to do this, in a platform-specific way. Win32 offers functions such as [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674(VS.85).aspx) where you can directly poke values into the memory space of another process. Most operating systems offer a shared memory function, with Win32 you can use memory mapped files and Unix flavours typically have some kind of equivalent "mmap" or "shmem" feature.

Answer (score 2):

I think that most operating systems are designed to make it impossible (or very difficult) to do what you are trying to do -- have one running program (or process) interfere with the contents of the address space of another running program (or process). Since you don't tell us your platform it's difficult to be categorical about this, but I suspect that the o/s is saving you from yourself. This rigid separation of processes is a safety feature on single-user machines, a safety and security feature on multi-user machines.

There are, of course, many techniques for running concurrent processes which can share memory or which exchange information by message-passing. Take some more time off school and study those!

Comment: @Mark - This topic interests me. Could you give me an example of some techniques used to 'share memory' or 'exchange information by message-passing'? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, Google around for 'shared-memory programming', for 'concurrent programming', 'message-passing programming'.  Wikipedia might be a good place to start.

Comment: Don't forget inter-process communication (IPC), named pipes, and sockets for everyday use cases of sharing data between programs

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at either Memory Mapped Files or Shared Memory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(VS.85).aspx